# Establish connection between Virtual Machiines across different locations

Tags: azure

I need to setup a performance test environment on the azure cloud. I need few VMs in East US, few VMs in Europe and few more in the Asia Region.
Than I need to establish connection between them.
If I create a cloud service and create multiple VMs under the same, those VMs can communication with each other. however, all VMs remain under a single region

same is the case for Virtual network.
Is there a way to setup environment as per my need

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're setting up, perf-wise, so it's a bit tough to give a proper answer. That said:

When you're crossing data centers, virtual networks won't help, as they're bound to a single data center. If VM `a` in one data center wants to talk with VM `b` in another data center, VM `a` will need to go through VM `b`'S public endpoint (and if you're trying to reach a specific VM, then make sure it's a direct endpoint, not load-balanced). Then, you can set up IP-based ACLs to allow only VM `a`'s IP address to access it (or come up with another security scheme).

As far as perf-testing: If you're actually creating a load between two VMs spanning 2 data centers, you'll have latency to contend with. I don't know what you're actually doing, so I don't know how (or if) this impacts you. Don't make any assumptions about the two datacenters talking directly with each other over high-speed interconnect - this traffic could easily be going through the public Internet.

Comment: Actually, I am using VSTS 2010 to generate the load. I want to have a controller machine and multiple agents. As the requirement is to have the distributed load, the agents machines are supposed to be in different regions. Controller sends instructions to agents for the load to be generated. If controller and agents are under same location (on windows azure) they can communicate.